Mailjetty bounce extension configuration
WP6.6.2  civi 5.74.4
Mailjet is fine sending emails but bounce notifications are not arriving in civi.
In mailjet I've set the end Url as "https://website.org.au/civicrm/mailjetty/webhook" and on testing this, a mailjet popup says "a test event has been successfully sent"
The docs say I should get "You should get a green OK, Code 200 on screen" but I assume the popup is equivalent?
Nothing in the civi logs showing bounce event
Docs also say "The recomendation from Mailjet is to configure
a username and password for Basic Auth and include that in your URL."
Is that imperative & if so how do I add (syntax) and what level civi user?
Many thanks in advance
Lesley

Event urls for permanent and temporary had not been added for mailgun webhook.
Re mailgunny it is only adding hard bounces - now need to investigate why soft bounce thresholds are not being observed - will post as new question

The interface may have changed a bit but you should get something indicating the test event was successfully sent, so the popup sounds ok.
But you should get something in the Civi logs when the test event is sent.  Do you get any bounce information back to Civi?
The Basic Auth bit is not imperative (ie 'recommendation')  There is no signature in the webhook meaning that when Civi gets the webhook data it does not know definitely that it has come from Mailjet - so someone could mess with you sending bogus bounce info. You could configure Basic Auth at the webserver level so that a username/password is required before anyone can get to the webhook URL.  They suggest it but I have not tried that.  You would want to make sure you are correctly receiving webhook calls from Mailjet before attempting to restrict it with Basic Auth.

Thanks Aiden der I should have looked at log. error is
"2024-10-30 15:31:27+1100  [info] Mailgun Webhook received. Raw input stored as context.
Array
(
[raw] =>
)
2024-10-30 15:31:27+1100  [notice] Mailgun Webhook ignored (returning 406)
Array
(
[message] => Expected JSON but didn't get it.
)"
I'm assuming I don't need to have a bounce account set up, nor the cron job to fetch bounces?

There are some situations where bounce mails get sent back to the sender and would need to be processed via a bounce account - but most bounces will be handled by Mailgun and sent back to Civi via webhook, so no cron job is needed for that.

Thanks Aiden - so mailgun is detecting the bounce and the webhook is being received in civi but as above there's a weird " Mailgun Webhook received. Raw input stored as context" error message - any ideas about that one - thanks for you help btw

Just noting that the original question was about Mailjet but your comments here mention Mailgun.  Do you have both Mailjet and Mailgun configured?  They work very similarly but are different.

You are right Aiden - sorry i was trying to set up both and confused myself! have since got both working - thanks for your tip
